# Log of a negative number

Tags: logarithms, pi

Why is the log of $x$ equal to the log of the absolute value of $x$ plus $i$ times $\pi$?

$$\log(x)=\log(|x|)+i\pi\text{, for }x < 0$$

Where does the $\pi$ come from? Is it from a logarithmic identity?

I know it sounds silly, but I was not able to find an answer from existing solutions: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93051/how-to-find-logarithms-of-negative-numbers?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757670/logarithm-of-a-negative-number), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336580/log-of-negative-numbers).

Comment: It comes from the identity $e^{i\pi} +1 = 0$, we rearrange this to be $\log(-1) = i \pi$, then for any negative number, $\log(-x) = \log( (-1) \cdot (x) ) = \log(-1) + \log(x) = i \pi + \log(x)$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value)?

Comment: Probably it comes from $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Comment: someday, when you study complex analysis, you will understand that what you said is only approximately true...

Comment: If the universe is only real numbers the log of a negative number makes no sense.  But if the universe consists of complex numbers, then we have to define what $e^{i}$ could *possibly* mean.  Long story short and hand waving $e^{i\pi} = -1$ and $e^{a+bi} = e^a(\cos b + i \sin b)$ [research euler's formula].  So $\log -1 = i\pi$ and $\log -|m| = \log -1 + \log |m| = i\pi + \log|m|$.  So where did the $\pi$ come from.   It came from discovering if $e^{a + bi} $ is going to mean *anything* it has to mean $e^a(\cos b + i \sin b)$ and now exponents and trig are eternally linked and $\pi$ shows up.

Comment: You asked "why is this not always true" but you linked to [a page that says the formula _is_ always true](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+(log(-%7Cx%7C))+equal+to+(log(%7Cx%7C)%2Bi*pi)).

Comment: @DavidK Haha yeah I misread what it said. Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Comment: So, I'm working with hypercomplex numbers and seeing that introducing negative reals produce a complex result, I was just wondering, how do you interpret this once your domain is say, the quaternions (or more)? I would think that the negative reals are no more related to i than j, k, etc.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

$e^{πi} + 1 = 0$.

$e^{πi} = -1$.

$πi = \log(-1)$.

$\log(-1) + \log(|a|) = \log(-|a|)$.

$\log(-|a|) = \log(|a|)+iπ$.

Comment: first equation should be $e^{(2k+1)\pi i}$

Comment: that's a fair add, but this response was catered to his result @LQ

Answer (score 16):

The standard explanation would go like this:

> Any complex number $z$ can be written in polar form:
>   $$z = |z|e^{i\theta}.$$
>   So, if we want to define the complex logarithm, we do so as follows:
>   $$\log (z) = \log(|z|e^{i\theta}) = \log(|z|) + \log(e^{i\theta}) = \log(|z|) + i\theta.$$
>   In particular, the logarithm of a negative real number $x$ can then be calculated as
>   $$\log (x) = \log(|x|e^{i\pi}) = \log(|x|) + \log(e^{i\pi}) = \log(|x|) + i\pi.$$

However, this explanation is not sufficient and the logarithm as presented is NOT a well-defined function. The angle $\theta$ is, well, an angle, and hence only defined up to multiples of $2\pi$: 
$$|z|e^{i\theta} = |z|e^{i(\theta+k2\pi)}$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, **the complex logarithm is only defined up to multiples of $2\pi i$ !**

For example:
$$\log (x) = \log(|x|e^{i\frac{3}{2}\pi}) = \log(|x|) + \log(e^{i\frac{3}{2}\pi}) = \log(|x|) + i\frac{3}{2}\pi,$$
or maybe 
$$\log (x) = \log(|x|e^{-i\frac{177}{2}\pi}) = \log(|x|) + \log(e^{-i\frac{177}{2}\pi}) = \log(|x|) - i\frac{177}{2}\pi.$$
But clearly $\pi \neq \frac{3}{2}\pi \neq -\frac{177}{2}\pi$. The point is: the complex logarithm is not a function, but what we call a multivalued function. To turn it into a proper function, we must restrict what $\theta$ is allowed to be, for example $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$. This is called the **principal complex logarithm** and is usually denoted by $\operatorname{Log}$ (capital L).

Technically, it doesn't matter to what range you restrict $\theta$, as long as the resulting logarithm is a proper function (not a multivalued function) and **you are consistent in your restriction of $\theta$**. For example, the following "proof" can be obtained if you're sloppy:
\begin{align}
e^{\pi i} = -1 & \implies (e^{\pi i})^2 = (-1)^2 & \text{ (square both sides)}\\
& \implies e^{2\pi i} = 1 & \text{ (calculate the squares)}\\
& \implies \log (e^{2\pi i}) = \log(1) & \text{ (take the logarithm)}\\
& \implies 2\pi i  = 0 & \text{ (calculate the logarithms)}
\end{align}
Clearly this is wrong!

Comment: Very clear. Thank you. I expect I'm being stupid, but I don't understand why, under "for example", it's $$\log(x)=\log(|x|e^{I\tfrac 32\pi})$$ and not $$\log(x)=\log(|x|e^{I 3\pi})$$ and so on.

Answer (score 7):

Slightly tongue in cheek but partially seriously I'm going to say "magic".

What I mean is before we talk about $\ln -k$ for a negative number we have to *define* what on earth it could possibly mean to have $e^{m} = -k$. There is no "natural" meaning to that and mathematicians, in one sense, must contrive a meaning for it. If our universe is the real numbers then this is .... impossible. If $b > 0$ then $b^x > 1$ and $e^x$ being negative is simply impossible.

But what if our universe is the complex numbers.  Then if $z = a + bi$ ($i^2 = -1$) then what could $e^{a+bi}$ possibly mean?  After all we can't just "multiply $e$ by itself the square root of negative one times".

Well, we know for real numbers, $e^{x + y} = e^xe^y$ and $\frac {de^x}{dx} = e^x$.  For this to still be true for complex numbers as well as for real numbers the only way to define $e^{z}$ where $z$ is a complex number, so that $e^{z+w} = e^ze^w$ and so that $\frac {d^z}{dz}$ the *only* possible way for that to stay true we have to define $e^{a+bi} = e^a(\cos b + i \sin b)$.

Okay.  That was ... a lot of hand waving.  But it works and if you study complex analysis it will be derived in great detail.  *BUT* this means....

$e^{i\pi} = e^{0 + i\pi} =  e^0(\cos \pi + i \sin \pi) = 1*(-1 + i*0) = -1$.

This is Euler's Formula,  one of the most famous mathematical formula in history.

Suddenly $e^z$ being a negative number is not impossible.  But if $e^z$ is negative then we need to have $e^{z} = e^{a + bi} = e^a(\cos b + i \sin b)$ so $\cos b + i \sin b$ is a negative number.  That means $b = \pi$ . So $z = i \pi$.

So this means $\ln -1*x = \ln -1 + \ln x = i\pi + \ln x$.

And that's where $\pi$ comes from.  When we define $e^{a+bi} = e^a(\cos b + i \sin b)$, exponents become thoroughly linked with trigonometric functions.  As such, $\pi$ is an essential part of the inverse.

For the real numbers only and logs of positive real numbers only, we don't have to worry as $e^x = e^{x + 0*i} = e^x(\cos 0 + i \sin 0) = e^x(1 + i*0) = e^x= k$ and $\ln k = x$ and $\pi$ is not relevant.