# Maximal domain question related to the function $f(x) = \ln((x-1)^{2} - m)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f(x) = \ln((x-1)^{2}-m)$, where $m$ is a constant.

Question: state the maximal domain over which $f$ is defined for the case where $m > 0$?

Issue: how to go about it?

Thought process so far:

-Inside function must be greater than zero. We hence end up with $((x-1)^{2}-m)> 0$. Define $f(x)$ on CAS, but I get lost at what domain to use.

Comment: Dear Jason, welcome to MSE! Please let us know what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You would have, $$x>1\pm\sqrt{m}$$ if you solved the above equation. Putting this into set builder notation, we have $$\{x|x\in\mathcal R \quad and\quad x>1\pm\sqrt m\}$$ This is the only area of the real numbers where the logarithm is defined. Unless you extend it to the complex plane (i.e. use the principle logarithm so that it isn't multivalued) and set every negative integer $-\ell$ equal to $|\ell |e^{i\pi}$ then the principal logarithm is $$\operatorname{Log}(-\ell)=\log(|\ell|)+i\pi$$ this allows us to redefine it in the complex plane as $$\{z|z\in \mathcal R \}$$ or $$\{z| \arg z \in\{\pi,2\pi\}\}$$ by the definition of the principal logarithm. If you want to learn more about complex logarithms, check out this question: [Log of a negative number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2089690).